# Check if friend is online

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm creating a messaging web app similar to whatsapp with Socket IO, but I'm having a problem with detecting if the user that is in my contact list is online or offline.

I have implemented a function called "new user" where every time a new client connects to the server it will add them to an array and then broadcast it to all clients after that the client loops through all the array and checks which one is in its contact list to determine if its online or not.

The problem is that imagine if there are 50.0000 users connecting and disconnecting. All clients would have to update and compare all online users with their contact list each time. That sounds like a really inefficient way to do it.

Any ideas?

**Server:**

```js
socket.on('new user', function(data, callback) {

    if (data in nicknames) {
        callback(false);
    } else {
        callback(true);
        socket.nickname = data;
        nicknames[socket.nickname] = 1;
        console.log("connected "+socket.nickname);
        updateNickNames();  
    }
});

socket.on('disconnect', function(data) {
    if(!socket.nickname) return;
    delete nicknames[socket.nickname];
    console.log("disconnected "+socket.nickname);
    updateNickNames();

});

function updateNickNames() {
    io.sockets.emit('usernames', nicknames);
}
```

**Client:**

```js
socket.on('usernames', function(data) {
    for (var username in data) {
        for(var i = 0; i < contactList.length; i++) {
            if(username == contactList[i]){
                alert("user "+contactList[i]+" online");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: _"Any ideas?"_ on how to create a scalable chat system? Yes, a few. Do you have a specific question about a programming language or piece of code?

Comment: Are you really going to have 500,000 users?

Comment: It sounds like your client/server relationship is reversed. Only serve content to a client when the client makes a request for it.

Comment: Why do you need to broadcast the entire array every time there's an update? Why not just broadcast the single user which changed status?

Comment: When a user comes online, you can only emit messages to the sockets of connected users who have them as contacts, if it's easy/cheap for you to calculate that list (probably yes, even at large scale). The other option would be for each user to poll on a regular basis to ask "who are my contacts online right now?", but in that case why use a socket framework at all?

Comment: Did you send `new user` message from the client? You can use  `contactList.indexOf(username)`  to "save" a couple of keystrokes.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit No I'm not having 500.000 users, I'm having a billion ;)

Comment: @4castle you are right thats more efficient but it still doesn't solve the problem with broadcasting to that many users

Comment: @Jaromanda X Well....... Thats what this hole post is about. Thanks bud

Comment: Sorry, was being tongue in cheek :p will remove the stupid comment :p